# change all of self-closing matches to xhtml closing syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex

> /<(\w+)>(?!\w)(?!(</(\1)>))/gm

and for instance I have a text like this

```
RegExr was created by gskinner.com.

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.

The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.
amir
Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.
<p>sdf,m.,.msdf</p><p><p><p><p></p>
<b></b>
<p><b><g>
<img>
<br><p><hr>
<p>
```

all in all ,this regex match with stand alone tag like the last `<p>`
I want to insert `/` character before the last character in each matches.
what I want is a match case like `<p>` becomes `</p>`
the actual problem is that I don't know how to run a replace method for each matches individually.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SteveTomlin did you read the last paragraph carefully?!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your post is not clear. You have a regex. You have text. You want to replace the last character with / but there is no 'replace' method in the first place

Comment: @SteveTomlin I changed the title for you but you didn't run it even once to figure out what is the problem to figure out what is my solution .if it was too obvious I did not ask question here .

Comment: ok let me help you - Where is your replace method?

Comment: @SteveTomlin if I have written it already i could ask here though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252505/discussion-between-amir-kian-and-steve-tomlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function to find all standalone tags then convert them to xhtml closing tag

```
function insertAtIndex(str, substring, index) {
            return str.slice(0, index) + substring + str.slice(index);
        }

    function OptimzeFileContent(FileContent) {`enter code here`

        let regexp = /<(\w+)>(?!\w)(?!(<\/(\1)>))/gm;

        let matches = [...FileContent.matchAll(regexp)];
        let insertPlace = [];
        let countAddedCharacter = 0;
        matches.forEach((match) => {
            console.log('match.index:', match.index);
            var insertCursor = FileContent.indexOf(">", match.index);
            insertPlace.push(insertCursor );
        });
        var extendedLengh = 0;
        console.log('insertPlace:', insertPlace);
        insertPlace.forEach((item) => {
               FileContent= insertAtIndex(FileContent, '/', item+extendedLengh);
            extendedLengh += 1;
        });
        return FileContent;
    }
```

Comment: tnx,you made my day